# Xcode stays on "Running" but don't run my app

Tags: xcode

I just updated my mac to Mountain Lion and installed the last version ox Xcode (4.6.3) and it works fine until I want to run any application. It compile and stay on "Running" but no app is launched. And I have to Force Quit XCode to stop this state, it is like frozen, but still reacting to my mouse inputs.

I reinstalled XCode, tried different Apple XCode projects but the issue stays the same.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: The latest version is Xcode 4.6.3.

Comment: You're right. I meant 4.6.3.

Comment: OK. 4.6.2 had some issues with Mountain Lion, but then I have no idea what the reason for your problem might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing the computer. No solution to my problem. Maybe a corrupted OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting the simulator?

***iOS Simulator Menu > Reset Content and Settings***
[image: simulator menu]

If that didn't work, change the debugger of your application to none.

***In Xcode: Your app scheme > Edit Scheme > From the side menu choose "Run yourapp.app" > Info tab > From the debugger menu choose "None"***
[image: scheme options]

Then try running your application.